# Display "per attribute" link in product page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I've been seeking everywhere to find a tip which should be obvious in Wordpress/Woocommerce. I want to make attribute values displayed in the product page as archive links each automatically generated. Does anyone know how to do that? The code page is :

```
<?php
            if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] )  {

                $values = woocommerce_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], 'names' );
                echo  apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values ) ;

            } else {

                // Convert pipes to commas and display values
                $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );

            }
        ?>
```

Can Anyone help?
Thanks!
F.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on this. Just found it in github

https://gist.github.com/coenjacobs/2594985